# Converting a vector's values to char pointer for write syscall

Tags: c, system-calls

I am having some trouble with using `write()`. I have a `vector<long>` that has several different long values in it. My ultimate goal is to convert this vector into a char pointer so that I can pass it to `write` and print the values to stdout.

Here is my code:

```
void print_vector(vec* v)
{
    int init_capacity = 10;
    char* output = (char*) malloc(init_capacity*sizeof(char));
    int cols = (int) sqrt(v->size);


    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        if(i==init_capacity)
        {
            init_capacity *= 2;
            output = (char*)realloc(output, init_capacity*sizeof(char));
        }
        const int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%l", v->data[i]);
        char buffer[n+1];
        int c = snprintf(buffer, n+1, "%l", v->data[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
            strcat(buffer, '\n');
        }

        output[i] = buffer;
    }

    write(1, output, init_capacity);
//    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
//    {
//        printf("%ld ", v->data[i]);
//        if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
//            puts("");
//        }
//    }

}
```

I first initialize the char* that I am planning to pass as the buffer to `write`. I give it an initial capacity of `10`, and as I loop through the vector and pass its values to my buffer `output`, I reallocate space if I run out.

In my for-loop, I first check to see if my `output` has run out of space and realloc if I need to.

I then load the `ith` element of my vector into `buffer` (not to be confused with `output`). I do this because I want to add a `"\n"` at the end of the last value in a column (this is supposed to look like a matrix). You'll see that at the second if statement in the code, where I concatenate "\n" to buffer.

I am doing somethign very wrong because I am getting a segfault.

There are two reasons I think this is happening:

1. I suspect there is something I am doing wrong with `buffer`. I don't know what it could be though... maybe `char buffer[n+1]` isn't happy? I really am not sure.
2. I might be misunderstanding the inputs for `strcat`. Does buffer not belong there?
3. I am fairly certain `output[i]= buffer` is incorrect.

I need help with this, and hopefully some explanation.

**This is a homework problem**. You don't have to give me the exact answer. That would be nice though if there is explanation to go with it - what I am really looking for is an example.

I have included in the comments below `write()` what I want to do.

Edit:

New code:

```
void print_vector(vec* v)
{
    int cols = (int) sqrt(v->size);
    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
    {
        int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%ld", v->data[i]);
        char buffer[n+1];
        sprintf(buffer, n+1, "%ld", v->data[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
            strcat(buffer, "\n");
        } else {
            strcat(buffer, " ");
        }

        write(1, buffer, n+1);
    }


//    for (int i = 0; i < v->size; i++)
//    {
//        printf("%ld ", v->data[i]);
//        if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
//            puts("");
//        }
//    }
}
```

When I run gdb, I get this output:

```
program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strchrnul_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strchr.S:32
32  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strchr.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

Which I imagine isn't helpful...

Some warnings I get when I compile:

```
$ make
gcc -g -o ctp transpose.c vec.c -lm
transpose.c: In function ‘print_vector’:
transpose.c:59:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘sprintf’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         sprintf(buffer, n+1, "%ld", v->data[i]);
                         ^
In file included from transpose.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:320:12: note: expected ‘const char * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 extern int sprintf (char *__restrict __s,
```

Comment: `strcat(buffer, '\n');` may write beyond `buffer` size which is `n+1`

Comment: C does not have vectors in the C++ sense, nor does `vector<long>` seem to make sense in C context.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, you are write - I have a vector file that I am including (and using).

Comment: Do you really have to put all the output into one big buffer before you `write` it?  You could use a fixed-size, automatic buffer if instead you formatted and wrote one element at a time.

Comment: `output[i] = buffer` cannot be okay: you're copying a pointer in a char. There are too many errors in that code.

Comment: first thing: enable all warnings.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that is a good idea - I might do that instead.

Comment: And do you have to use `write()`? You could just use a loop that does `fprintf(stdout, "%ld\n", v->data[i]);`

Comment: @Barmar yes unfortunately, I have to use system calls for I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `snprintf()` the second time, you can just use `sprintf()`. The first call told you how long the output will be, and you allocated enough space for that when you declared `buffer`. So you don't have to worry about buffer overflow when you actually write it.

And if you do use `snprintf()`, you shouldn't use `n+2` as the limit. Since you need to allow room for the newline, you should use `n+1`.

The `if` statement needs an `else` clause that writes a space, so you'll have something between the columns in the matrix.

```
    if ((i + 1) % cols == 0) {
        strcat(buffer, "\n");
    } else {
        strcat(buffer, " ");
    }
```

Note also that the second argument to `strcat()` must be a string, not a `char`.

If you really want this to look like a nice matrix, you should specific a width for your output in the format string, so all the columns will be the same size. This also means that you don't need to specify the size of `buffer` dynamically, it just needs to be big enough for that width.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't understand why I don't need the second `snprintf` call thought. The first one loads v->data[i] into NULL, and I only use it to get `n`. The second one however will actually load it into `buffer`. Is that correct? If i don't need it, how do I actually get `v->data[i]` into buffer?

Sorry for my late response.

Comment: I meant you can just use ordinary `sprintf()` instead of `snprintf()`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I am very confused as to why sprintf() resolved my `segfault` error - why did snprintf throw segfault and not sprintf?

Comment: The problem was the incorrect argument to `strcat()`, nothing to do with sprintf versus snprintf.

Comment: Wait, I might have accidentally run an older version of the code. I am still getting segfault. I posted gdb's output. When I comment out print_vec()'s code and uncomment the commented portion, it works fine though... any ideas?

Comment: You changed to `sprintf()`, but you kept the `n+1` argument. Why aren't you checking compiler warnings, it should complain about passing `int` when `char *` is required.

Comment: It should be `char buffer[n+2];` to allow room for the newline and null byte.

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you so much, it's always really nice to find experienced people on stackoverflow not berate noobs. Much appreciated!